# Sorting in java using lambda Expression

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

```
class Solution {
    public int[] Sort(int[] nums) {
       int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Arrays.sort(arr, (a, b) -> (a+""+b).compareTo((b+""+a)));//this part is showing error
        return arr;
       
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this code is not working?

I am trying to sort an array based on concatenated results.

Comment: What does "*is not woring*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.

Comment: You can't sort an `int` array with a custom comparator. Try `Integer`.

Comment: I was wondering why this code  gave compilation error. But now I understand that comparators can be used only with objects and here I used int[]. Thanks for the tip..!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your problem correctly, but this is one way to sort it with logic you initially showed.

```
public int[] Sort(int[] nums) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
            .sorted((a, b) ->
                    (Integer.valueOf(a+""+b).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b+""+a)))
            ).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

In this case we use `.boxed()` to convert from `int` to `Integer` so we have `.sorted()` available to use. Actual concat sort algo you can adjust to your liking, and then we map to `int` and collect to array.